# KDE4 - possible to mount flash disks etc. on the desktop like in KDE3?

Tags: linux, kde, usb-flash-drive, removable

my grandfather uses a linux machine for web browsing, emails etc. So he mostly uses Firefox, Thunderbird and sometimes also Skype and now he has also Jabber account. Currently there is Pclinuxos 2009 installed (the newest one with KDE 3.5). I used a frozen community repository, but this also brings the problem I cannot update the used programs as I am afraid it would attempt to replace the old KDE as well.

I know I can update Mozilla apps by downloading a static rpm and install with KPackage or Konsole and similar with LibreOffice. Not much friendly... I also discussed switching to other WM - but GNOME surely not, maybe Xfce (other ones have other issues).

Is it possible to somehow make KDE4 to behave like KDE3.5 in some ways? At least auto-mounting of flash drives etc. directly on the desktop would be helpful as searching in system tray etc. is not optimal solution. Would prefer the old one.

thanks

Comment: you could probably consider the [trinity project](http://www.trinitydesktop.org/) if you didn't mind switching distros - i'd suggest the debian squeeze varient.

Comment: Thanks for hint. However, switching to Debian is not good way for me. I already have some negative experience with Lenny and I am used to work with all the user-friendly clicking tools. :-)

Comment: there's an ubuntu option, but they're a little behind. Funny thing is i know another person who swears by KDE 3.x, and uses pclinuxos2009 ;p

Comment: In my case it was a love at first sight. After knoppix, ubuntu etc. I tried Pclinuxos 0.92 (2005) and we stick with Pclinuxos. Later tried newer Ubuntu, Mandriva, Elive, Vector ... but no reason to switch. Maybe Unity linux or Mageia ...

Comment: It seems like flash drives mounting is good enough. It's not as bad as you've written, especially if Dolphin file manager is used. If this is your only problem, you should consider switching to KDE 4.7 right now.

Comment: @BlaXpirit: KDE 4.7 uses different approach? However, I discussed this with grandpa a he prefers to keep current WM - so KDE 3 and Konqueror. I will probably update only certain packages like Firefox, Thunderbird and add LibreOffice and leave the rest untouched.

Comment: @Juhele: *KDE 4.7* doesn't use different approach from KDE 4 overall, it's just totally worth switching to. Dolphin file manager is very good: it's simple by default, but has all kinds of tricks if you look through the settings (but you can still use Konqueror). About the **approach**, I wrote it in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about others, but here's how it happens with Kubuntu and Dolphin if you do not change any settings:
You insert a flash drive, a notification appears that lets you mount it and/or open the drive in a file manager; if you ignore the notification, the flash drive is in the devices/shortcuts list of Dolphin anyway (not mounted yet, but mounts as soon as you try to open it).

If you go to **Device Notifier** Settings, however, things get even better. There's a whole **Automounting** tab, where you can *Automatically mount removable media when attached*, or *Only automatically mount removable media that has been manually mounted before*. One more interesting thing is *Automount on Login*.

This is KDE! You can make everything perfect, just look through the settings!

Comment: Yes, I know this. I tried Mageia and Pclinuxos - both have luckily automount set by default, so this is not problem. Unmount is the problem as KDE4 has similar approach as Win7 and you have to go to "system tray", find the right icon, choose appropriate action and then finally pull the thumbdrive from usb. In fact I have no problem with this, but try to persuade 80 years old person to change his computer habits (switched to linux few years ago). I will rather sacrifice the system update to keep the UI intact

Comment: @Juhele: You can unmount right in Dolphin.

Comment: @Juhele: Also, the unmount process is only 2 clicks even if you do it through system tray.